# Drupal user redirected to MoneyScript checkout page after registration

Tags: drupal-7, user-registration

We are registering users in our Drupal system via REST services call from 3rd party system.
What happens is that the user is redirected to "ms/checkout" after successful registration and gets a 403-Forbidden message. Any thoughts on why this might be happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

May be its issue of permission. Go to Permissions page and allow annonymous user to access Cart, Checkout page.

Comment: Actually, I do not want the anonymous user to be going there. Can you tell me if there exists any setting to disable this redirect?